# Solution of wave equations in the presence of various form of potentials?

Tags: waves, potential, resource-recommendations, differential-equations

The solutions of the wave equation are influenced by the inclusion of a potential term in the equation. I would like to understand if there exists a general rule that allows for predicting changes in the wave solution or behavior based on the shape or form of the introduced potential.

Additionally, I am seeking references on solving wave equations when various potentials are present.

Comment: @okba are you looking for solutions to the basic 1D wave equation?  They are given by D'Alembert's solution.  I think what you call potentials would come in as initial conditions.